# Object property disappears when converting to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Here's my class:

```
export class Patient {
constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public location: string, public bedId: number, public severity: string,
public trajectory: number, public vitalSigns: [GraphData[]], public latestReading: GraphData[]){
}
 public get getCombinedVSData(): Array<GraphData>{
    let combinedVitalSigns: GraphData[] = [];
    for (let data of this.vitalSigns){
        combinedVitalSigns.push(data[0]);
    }
    return combinedVitalSigns;
}
```

}

When I print one of my patients,

```
console.log(this.patientService.patients[0]);
```

I get this:

[image]

In my application, I need to convert the patient to JSON to move it with drag and drop:

```
let thisIsNotFine=JSON.stringify(this.patientService.patients[0]);
```

Here comes the problem. When I convert it back to a JS object and print it,

```
console.log(JSON.parse(thisIsNotFine));
```

I get this:

[image]

As you can see, it is no longer called a `Patient` in the console, and the `getCombinedVSData` getter is gone.

Is this normal behaviour? How can I keep the getter on the object when converting it to JSON? Thank you.

Comment: if you convert back from json string you get instance of Object. to get a instance of Pation use: `let result = (JSON.parse(myJsonString) as Patient);`

Comment: **Voted to reopen this question.** The “JSON stringify ES6 class property with getter/setter” question, which this question marked as a duplicate of, is about excluding specific properties when JSON-stringifying. This is about JSON not preserving functions. How come they are the same questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JSON docs](http://www.json.org/), JSON can't include functions so your method won't be parsed as JSON. Valid data types are string, number, object, array, true, false and null.

Here's an example of `json.stringify()` and `json.parse()` removing methods from an object:

```js
var obj = {
 "prop" : "value",
    "method" : function( num ){
     return num + 1;
    }
};

var json = JSON.stringify( obj );

var new_obj = JSON.parse( json );

Object.keys( new_obj ).forEach(function(key){
 console.log( key + " : " + new_obj[key]  );
});
```

Comment: You can, however, pass a function as the second argument to `JSON#stringify` to define custom behavior for when a function or other Object is encountered, such as calling the .toString().
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter

Comment: If this solves your problem you could accept the answer so that people will know this is resolved?

Comment: It's not a normal method; it's a property getter. Similar problem, but a little different explanation. A good way to do it, besides the second argument to `stringify`, is to use [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, nice, I didn't know that.